# Accessibility Full Screen Selection Issue

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility, blocked

I have a tableView which is the table is `UITableViewStyleGrouped` style. Whose cell elements are accessible. But as soon as you select the outer area of the cell but within the table view the whole screen gets selected (as you can see black outline) and that time you will not be able to scroll using three fingers. Only selection sound comes.

I have mentioned in the attached image which is a screenshot of 
[image]

Tried setting isAccessibilityElement for tableview, header and footer view as well. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is how TableView works with VoiceOver.  If you select a cell in the tableView, you should be able to scroll.